# looking for dtrace script to list top used nfs files

Tags: nfs, solaris, solaris-10, dtrace

I'm currently using https://github.com/siebenmann/cks-dtrace/blob/master/nfs3-mon.d to identify most active datasets on our NFS server (Solaris 10)

Unfortunately I need to dig deeper, and I would like to be able to track down most used files. Is there a way to list top X files for various operations?

I'm not dtrace guru and was not able to find answer in few hours..

Comment: Where are you running your dTrace script(s)?  On the NFS server or on the client(s)?

Comment: We are running it on NFSv3 server

Answer (score 1):

The docs for the NFS DTrace provider are pretty good on the [Oracle website](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E36784_01/html/E36846/glhkq.html). The scripts in particular that look useful to you are `nfsv3fileio.d` or (to get a *lot* more data that you might have to post-process) `nfsv3rwsnoop.d`.

Assuming you mean "most used" as in "highest number of reads / writes", and you don't care about the proportion between those or who is doing them, a simple script to print the filenames and the IO count to each of them is:

```
nfsv3:::op-read-start, nfsv3:::op-write-start {
     @[args[1]->noi_curpath] = count();
}

tick-10sec {
    printa(@);
    trunc(@);
}
```

(I didn't run this because I don't have any NFS shares set up, but I think it will work.) To summarize what it's doing:

1. `nfsv3:::op-{read|write}-start` are the events that trigger when a read or a write begins on an NFSv3 share. Each time one of those happens, the event gets an argument `args[1]` that contains the variable `noi_curpath`, which gives the file's path (if available; occasionally it's not cached so you get nothing). We use that as a key, and use the `count()` of times this happens as the value in a map named `@`.
2. `tick-10sec` is an event that triggers every 10 seconds, starting 10 seconds after the script begins. It first prints the map with `printa()`, and then clears the values in it with `trunc()` so we get fresh data for the next 10 second window.

Comment: Note that the document you linked is Solaris 11.  OP is running Solaris 10, so the Solaris 11 scripts may not work, especially for NFSv4.